# Turn off caching of lightning components of quick actions

Tags: lightning

I have a quickaction that is overridden by a lightning component. Apparently lightning caches the component or something because calling the quick action from two different records brings up the same component with the same data; a manual refresh will then correct the issue. Is there anyway to change this behavior rather than hacking something out ?

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the cache in the setup (see how to in the answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134111/salesforce-lightning-component-cache)), although it'll affect performance for all users using lightning.

Not ideal, but can't think of a better solution.

Comment: Thanks I have seen that. That is for components under development, which seems like annoying but somewhat expected behavior. My problem is that the exact same initialized component is called by a quick action in two entirely seperate records

Comment: this can't be expected behavior.

Comment: And in fact, that setting is unchecked in the org

Comment: I hear, strange behavior. Figured if you hadn't tried this setting, it was worth a shot