# Unable to rerender a lightning component once the apex method is called

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm building a lightning component using the new `Lightning Web Component` framework, the component retrieves information from a custom setting with three checkboxes, once the user changes the values of those fields, and hits Save, the record is updated. If I navigate to the Home tab, and then I come back to the custom tab that contains the component, it shows the previous value. It has to be something with the cache, any ideas?

**NOTE:** The `getMyValues` method returns something back to the component, only if I set `(cacheable=true)`

.html

```
<form>
    <lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group"
    label="Checkbox Group"
    options={options}
    value={value}
    onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-around_medium"> 
    </lightning-checkbox-group>
</form>
<lightning-button label="Save" title="Save" onclick={handleSaveClick} />
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getMyValues from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.getMyValues';
import setMyValues from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.setMyValues';

    export default class CheckboxGroupBasic extends LightningElement {

        @track value = [];

        @wire (getMyValues)
        wiredMyValues({error, data}){
            let deserializedData;
            if (data){
                deserializedData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (deserializedData.Value1)
                    this.value.push('value-1')
                if (deserializedData.Value2)
                    this.value.push('value-2')
            }
        }

        handleSaveClick() {
            // DML action here... // WORKS FINE
        }
    }
```

apex controller

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getMyValues(){
    ConfigOptions__c config =  ConfigOptions__c.getValues('My Config');
    return JSON.serialize(config);
}
```

Comment: you will need to share a minimal reproduceable code sample  for better assistance

Comment: As glls mentioned it is hard to say for sure with the limited information, but [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134111/salesforce-lightning-component-cache) may help you.