# Lightning Web Component not using updated code unless cookies are cleared and re-log in

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I'm building a Lightning Component. It works, but whenever I push a substantial update of code, it will only display the update in the browser %20 of the time.

When I clear cookies and log back in, my new code that was not displaying before the refresh, is now working as expected. **Is there a way to ensure the LWC will display the new code base without having to clear cookies and log back in?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

`Setup --> Session Settings --> Turn off "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance"`

As the [Salesforce Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sessions.htm&type=5) mention:

This'll allow you to avoid having to clear the cache and do a [hard reload](https://www.documate.org/automation/what-is-a-hard-refresh-how-to-do-a-hard-refresh-in-any-browser/) to see code changes. I make sure to always check this setting off in development orgs. Just make sure not to do so in production.

[image]

If you find you're still not seeing the latest changes consistently, you can enable [lightning debug mode](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_debug_mode.htm&type=0) for yourself

`Setup --> Debug Mode`

Select yourself and click on enable debug mode.

[image]

---

If you're *creating* scratch orgs, you can set the [enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_mobilesettings.htm) to `false` in your definition file to disable secure and persistent browser caching as well:

```
...
    "settings": {
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup that worked. Solid stuff. How did you figure that out?

Comment: I was fed up with the same thing you were a couple years back and went on a search and found the docs. I think they also mentioned in the release notes (maybe Summer 19?) that they were making this worse (in the sense that changes would take longer to show up with simple refreshes).

Comment: Here is a similar question that provides more detail https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134111/salesforce-lightning-component-cache

Comment: To me, the much bigger issue is in Production where thousands of our customers in a community are not getting the latest versions of components release which break functionality.  Is there a long term solution?  Is there a way to write code that forces the browser to use the updated version of a component?

Comment: @SfdcHawkeye - I've turned this setting off in production for 5-10 minutes or so after a production deployment if it was needed for situations like you're describing. This allows end users to simply refresh and get the latest component. Then, I turn it back on.

Comment: You can't be fully sure all users will return to the site within 5-10 minutes.  Especially in a community of 20K users from all over the globe.  Some might not return for a few days, weeks or months.  Do we know what the expiration duration is of the cached components?

Comment: @SfdcHawkeye I definitely think it's worth you're own question

Comment: Changing this setting is not giving me a predictable outcome. I tried it in a sandbox and on production, but for me it is not a guaranteed solution.

Comment: Are you doing a [hard refresh](https://www.documate.org/automation/what-is-a-hard-refresh-how-to-do-a-hard-refresh-in-any-browser/)? I haven't noted any issue with this.

Comment: After a hard refresh it works. But a hard refresh also worked when I didn't change this setting. I would like my users to see the newest version without having to do the hard refresh themselves.

Comment: If it's not working for you in sandboxes, I would also enable [lightning debug mode](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_debug_mode.htm&type=0) on yourself and let me know if that provides a more consistent behavior. If that is still inconsistent, I'd suggest a support case as it's the documented setting(s) to turn off in sandboxes and it's possible maybe a recent browser update (or Salesforce release) has affected it. For Production, I think it would be a great, separate question to ask considering the docs mention to not disable this in production anyway.